# Save Excel sheets as HTML

Tags: excel, applescript, osx-mavericks

I'm attempting to save each sheet in a workbook (`foo`,`bar`,`baz`) as a separate HTML document (`foo.html`,`bar.html`,`baz.html`):

```
set theDirectory to (path to desktop as text) & "Output:"

set theSource to choose file with prompt "Choose file:" default location "/Users/<user>/Desktop/" of type {"XLS", "XLSX"}

tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    activate

    set theWorkbook to open theSource

    set theSheets to every sheet of active workbook

    repeat with theSheet in theSheets

        set theDestination to theDirectory & (the name of theSheet) & ".html"
        log theDestination

        tell theSheet
            save as sheet filename theDestination file format HTML file format
        end tell

    end repeat

    quit saving no

end tell
```

This results:

- a folder in `Output` for each sheet (named `<sheet name>_files`) that contains an HTML document for each sheet (named `sheet<n>.html`), plus a few additional files (`filelist.xml`,`stylesheet.css`,`tabstrip.html`)
- a file in `Output` for each sheet (named .html`) that references the corresponding folder

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script:

```
set theSource to choose file with prompt "Choose file:" default location (path to desktop) of type {"XLS", "XLSX"}
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder:" default location path to desktop)
set thePath to (theDestination as text) & "data.HTML"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open theSource
    tell active workbook
        save as active sheet filename thePath file format HTML file format
    end tell
    quit saving no
end tell
```

Will generate:

- a file named `data.HTML`
- a folder named `data_files`, containing a document for each sheet (`sheet<NNN>.HTML`), plus additional files (`filelist.xml`,`stylesheet.css`,`tabstrip.html`)

Comment: Related Gists: https://gist.github.com/craibuc/41974122c555fdb07ee6, https://gist.github.com/craibuc/8ff2cf5aad43576bf247