# Export XLS file as HTML from Excel with Applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

I'm trying to export an Excel document (all sheets) as HTML. When using the code below I receive no errors and the script runs for several seconds (about 15) but never actually produces any output. I've tried replacing the file name "test.html" with a full path in both HFS and POSIX formats and I still get the same results -- nothing

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        tell active workbook
            save as sheets filename "test.html" file format HTML file format -- doesn't seem to actually work
        end tell
    end tell
```

If anyone can see my error and/or has successfully gotten this to work in the past, I would love an explanation to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803898/save-excel-sheets-as-html ?

Comment: @CRGreen Yes, same answer doesn't work for me. The line of code I highlighted is basically the same and I have tested many ways (one with an exact match to that answer) and it produces no output. I'm guessing good ol' Microsoft has created yet another bug. :(

Comment: dang. Sorry I don't have Office, otherwise I'd kill some time torturing it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both of these worked for me:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        save as active sheet filename (POSIX file "...full path here..." as text) file format HTML file format
    end tell
end tell


tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        save as active sheet filename "...full path here..." file format HTML file format
    end tell
end tell
```

(Although I would expect it to just export the active sheet, it actually dumps out all of the sheets in the workbook.)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2016 (15.28)

Comment: On version 15.34 I tried both of your options exactly with the same results... no output.
`tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   tell active workbook
    save as active sheet filename "/Users/myuser/Desktop/xxxxxx/example.html" file format HTML file format
   end tell
  end tell` and also `tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   tell active workbook
    save as active sheet filename "Macintosh SSD:Users:myuser:Desktop:xxxxxx:example.html" file format HTML file format
   end tell
  end tell`